# Item not getting selected through javascript file

Tags: php, jquery, joomla2.5

I have simple jquery file which slide news, but now some problem has occurred and it's not selecting element. while debugging it shos null value in triggers.

Code for  Php file

```
<?php
/**
 * copyright (C) 2008 GWE Systems Ltd - All rights reserved
 */

// Check to ensure this file is included in Joomla!
defined('_JEXEC') or die();

/**
 * HTML View class for the module  frontend
 *
 * @static
 */
include_once(JPATH_SITE."/modules/mod_jevents_latest/tmpl/default/latest.php");


class GeraintModLatestView extends DefaultModLatestView  
{

    function displayLatestEvents(){
        $document = JFactory::getDocument();

        $this->getLatestEventsData();

        $content = "";
        $var=count($this->eventsByRelDay);
        $testVar=1;
        if(isset($this->eventsByRelDay) && count($this->eventsByRelDay)){
            $content .='<html>';
            $content.='<body>';
            $urls= "http://localhost/Mineral/modules/mod_jevents_latest/tmpl/myjs/jquery.min.js";
            $content.='<script src="'.$urls.'"></script>';

            $urls= "http://localhost/Mineral/modules/mod_jevents_latest/tmpl/myjs/slideshow.js";
            $content.='<script src="'.$urls.'"></script>';
            $content.='<script>  jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>';
            $content.='<div style="height:200px; width=300px; overflow: hidden; position:relative; top:0; border:5px double #206BA4; border-radius:7px; text-align:center; ">';

            $content .= '<ul class="triggers" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">';

            // Now to display these events, we just start at the smallest index of the $this->eventsByRelDay array
            // and work our way up.
            $firstTime=true;
            $lastElem=false;
            // initialize name of com_jevents module and task defined to view
            // event detail.  Note that these could change in future com_event
            // component revisions!!  Note that the '$this->itemId' can be left out in
            // the link parameters for event details below since the event.php
            // component handler will fetch its own id from the db menu table
            // anyways as far as I understand it.

            $task_events = 'icalrepeat.detail';
            $this->processFormatString();

            foreach($this->eventsByRelDay as $relDay => $daysEvents){
                reset($last);
                reset($daysEvents);

                // get all of the events for this day
                foreach($daysEvents as $dayEvent){
                    if($testVar==$var)
                    $lastTime=true;
                    if(($dayEvent->bgcolor()=='#FF0000')&&($lastTime))
                    $dst = "text-decoration:blink;border-color:".$dayEvent->bgcolor();
                    else
                    $dst = "border-color:".$dayEvent->bgcolor();
                    if($firstTime) $content .= '<li  style="'.$dst.'">';
                    else $content .= '<li style="'.$dst.'">';

                    // generate output according custom string
                    foreach($this->splitCustomFormat as $condtoken) {

                        if (isset($condtoken['cond'])) {
                            if ( $condtoken['cond'] == 'a'  && !$dayEvent->alldayevent()) continue;
                            else if ( $condtoken['cond'] == '!a' &&  $dayEvent->alldayevent()) continue;
                            else if ( $condtoken['cond'] == 'e'  && !($dayEvent->noendtime() || $dayEvent->alldayevent())) continue;
                            else if ( $condtoken['cond'] == '!e' &&  ($dayEvent->noendtime() || $dayEvent->alldayevent())) continue;                            
                            else if ( $condtoken['cond'] == '!m' &&  $dayEvent->getUnixStartDate()!=$dayEvent->getUnixEndDate() ) continue;
                            else if ( $condtoken['cond'] == 'm' &&  $dayEvent->getUnixStartDate()==$dayEvent->getUnixEndDate() ) continue;
                        }
                        foreach($condtoken['data'] as $token) {
                            unset($match);
                            unset($dateParm);
                            $dateParm="";
                            $match='';
                            if (is_array($token)) {
                                $match = $token['keyword'];
                                $dateParm = isset($token['dateParm']) ? trim($token['dateParm']) : "";
                            }
                            else if (strpos($token,'${')!==false){
                                $match = $token;
                            }
                            else {
                                $content .= $token;
                                continue;
                            }

                            $this->processMatch($content, $match, $dayEvent, $dateParm,$relDay);
                        } // end of foreach
                    } // end of foreach

                    $content .= "</li>\n";
                    $firstTime=false;
                    $testVar++;
                } // end of foreach
            } // end of foreach
            //$content=var_dump($var);
            $content .="</ul>";
            $content .="</div>";
            $content .="</body>";
            $content .="</html>";

        } else {
            $content.='<div style="height:200px; width=300px; overflow: hidden; position:relative; top:0; border:5px double #206BA4; border-radius:7px; text-align:center; ">';
            $content .= '<ul class="mod_events_latest_table" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">';
            $content .= '<li class="mod_events_latest_first" >'. JText::_('JEV_NO_EVENTS') . '</li>' . "\n";
            $content .="</ul>\n";
            $content.='</div>';
        }

        $callink_HTML = '<div class="mod_events_latest_callink">'
        .$this->getCalendarLink()
        . '</div>';

        if ($this->linkToCal == 1) $content = $callink_HTML . $content;
        if ($this->linkToCal == 2) $content .= $callink_HTML;

        if ($this->displayRSS){
            $rssimg = JURI::root() . "media/system/images/livemarks.png";
            $callink_HTML = '<div class="mod_events_latest_rsslink">'
            .'<a href="'.$this->rsslink.'" title="'.JText::_("RSS_FEED").'" target="_blank">'
            .'<img src="'.$rssimg.'" alt="'.JText::_("RSS_FEED").'" />'
            .JText::_("SUBSCRIBE_TO_RSS_FEED")
            . '</a>'
            . '</div>';
            $content .= $callink_HTML;
        }

        return $content;
    } // end of function
} // end of class
```

Jquery file

```
$(window).load(function () 
{
    jQuery.noConflict();
    var triggers = $('ul.triggers li');
    var lastElem = triggers.length-1;
    var target;
    triggers.first().addClass('selected');
    triggers.hide().first().show();                         
    function sliderResponse(target)                         
      {
        triggers.removeClass('selected').
        fadeOut(9000).eq(target).addClass('selected').fadeIn(9000);
      }
    function sliderTiming() 
    {
         if(triggers.length==1)
        {
            triggers.first().show();
            clearInterval(timingRun);
        }
        else
       {
           target = $('ul.triggers li.selected').index();
            if ( target === lastElem ) 
                { target = 0; }
            else 
                { target = target+1; }

            sliderResponse(target);
       }
   }

   var timingRun = setInterval(function() { sliderTiming(); },9000);
    function resetTiming() 
    {
        clearInterval(timingRun);
        timingRun = setInterval(function() { sliderTiming(); },9000);
    }
});
```

The same file working correctly in other joomla template. and i think their must not be problem of any conflict as i have checked it by disabling other model.

Comment: Unless i'm wrong, the PHP file seems to be carrying out both a controller function and a view. It's super ugly and ridiculous to maintain :(

Comment: I am working on jevent module

Comment: those modules are not allowed to call proper views?

Comment: My question is I am able see ul and li element but script not working what may be the problem. It's working fine in another template.